# Device is unable to BOOT or INSTALL with generated .hddimg

Tags: intel, yocto

I have device which has following configuration:

- Chipset architecture - `Intel NM10 express`
- Processor - `Atom D2550 Dual Core`
- Display - `DVI`
- Volatile Memory - `2GB DDR3`
- Storage - `16GB`

**Objective**: Device should run yocto embededded OS successfully

What I have done,

- Downloaded three required yocto layers for warrior branch i.e. 1. poky 2. meta-openembedded 3. meta-intel
- Modified `local.conf` with `MACHINE ??= "intel-core2-32"`
- Ran `source poky/oe-init-build-env`
- Generated `.hddimg` by bitbake `core-image-minimal`
- Flashed `.hddimg` to thumb drive through `dd` command

Attached thumb drive to device and I could see BOOT and INSTALL option, upon clicking any of them nothing happens(not even logs) i.e. Blank screen

Troubleshooting I tried out are,

1. Tried to boot `lubuntu` and it was successful
2. Replaced kernel & initrd of `lubuntu` with yocto's one and booting was successful which indicates there is no issue with kernel or initrd in `.hddimg` generated by yocto
3. Tried some experiment with `syslinux` as well but didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

The `.hddimg` types are quite outdated these days, and meta-intel has also switched to `wic` Their `README` includes very good information on how to create boot- and installable images [here](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-intel/tree/README#n155) and [here](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-intel/tree/README#n201).

Short summary of it:

- for booting, use the `.wic`-file
- for building an installer, setup image and bootlader config according to documentation, then use `.wic`-file

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work out, with `.wic`-file I do not even see BOOT and INSTALL option.

Comment: @RaxeshOriya because you expect something that just is not provided currently. You can get a bootable image, as per the first link - or a image that installs itself, as per the second link. Thats what the docs tell you, and therefore is what meta-intel provides. If you expect something else, then you probably either have to look somewhere else or create it.